# What is the correct file type to handle jQuery AJAX in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to use `jQuery` `AJAX` in my `asp.net` web app. I an new to `aspnet`, having always used `PHP` before. My method of handling `AJAX` involves having one URL that handles all the `AJAX` requests, responding with `JSON`. My initial idea was to use a regular `.aspx` Web Form for this (as in `PHP` I just use a regular `PHP` file like any other page in the site), but then I saw VS2010 has all these other types of files that can be added, and was wondering of one of them was better (maybe already has some built-in functionality, or is lighter on resources and responds faster), as I am unfamiliar with any of them.

What would be the correct way to handle these `AJAX` requests?

P.S. Would my `Session` be available in my `AJAX` handler?

Comment: Which technology are you going to use? _WebForms_ or _MVC_? Ajax in _MVC_ will look familiar to you. On the other hand _WebForms_ normally use `UpdatePanels` to do the work (which may seem very different to what you were used to do).

Comment: WebForms (this is for a school project and I don't get to choose MVC or WebForms)

Comment: Then you better study [`UpdatePanels`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx). Plain ajax in webforms is a bit cumbersome (you will need to write static methods in the code-behind). `UpdatePanels` are very easy.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have only one file on the server side to handle all the ajax Requests

**ajax.aspx**

```
<%
    if (Request.QueryString["getRateofProd"] != null) {
        string prodid = Request.QueryString["getRateofProd"];
        Response.Write (getRate(prodid));
        return;
    }
    if (Request.QueryString[" <<< similarly other variables and requests >>> "] != null)
    {
        .... // Handle another GET Request
        return;
    }
%>
```

I can pass the values through URL to get the String response from the server by `GET` method

Every Client request is made by

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: 'ajax.aspx?getRateofProd=P1',
    success: function(response)
    {
        $('#<%=lblrate.ClientID%>').text(response);
    }
}
```

Use a Global Handler file to redirect all the requests for the `SERVER` to that file using ASP.NET URL Rewriting,

In PHP, Apache, there is `.htaccess` file Redirecting all the Requests. I don't know about the ASP.NET url Rewriting Sorry.

once any request is redirected to particular file `requestshandler.aspx` Detect if it is an Ajax request like

```
if(Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use jQuery in ASP.NET,

use `$.ajax()` [API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and use the post method to call a Web method on the ASP.NET code behind Asynchronously.

Follow this link how to call a web method ASP.NET

[Calling an ASP.NET Web method from $.ajax()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2282501/jquery-ajax-call-to-webmethod)

you can use this `$.ajax()` function in jQuery to handle the Asynchronous Request to the Server. and manually update the divs / panels in the Web page.

Comment: I know how to do the jQuery side. My question was about the server side.