# Javascript values to WebMethod

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, json, webmethod

I am trying to simply pass some values from Javascript into my codebehind for processing.
I just want to pass a `Number` and `Message` to the `WebMethod` but get different errors based on whatever thing I change.

JS:

```
function SendMessage() {
var number = document.getElementById("number").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;

var msg = {
    "Number": number,
    "Message": message
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/SendMessage",
    data: JSON.stringify(msg),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("Message sent");
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("Message call failed");
    }
});
}
```

In my codebehind I have a `WebMethod` defined and also a `Message` class to hold my message

```
[WebMethod]
public static void SendMessage(string message)
{
    //Create a  TMessage and deserialize to it

}
```

`Message`:

```
public class TMessage
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

My understanding is that I am receiving JSON and should deserialize it to a `Message` type.
However I have a breakpoint in the `SendMessage` method and it never gets hit, the error being returned is:
`Message=Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: 'message'.`

From some playing around earlier, I was able to get the breakpoint hit by changing the parameter from `string` to `object` (and some changes to the data: value in the Ajax call), but then it seemed I was receiving a `Dictionary` and I couldn't cast it to `TMessage`.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clearly look at webmethod , it has only one param i.e. `message` .

You need to pass this to ajax call. - `var params = "{'message':'" + message  + "'}";`

Helpful link - [Send JSON to webmethod?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527422/send-json-to-webmethod)

```
function SendMessage() {

var number = document.getElementById("phonenumber").value;
var message = document.getElementById("message").value;

var params = "{'message':'" + message + "', 'number':'" + number + "'}";
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Default.aspx/SendMessage",
    data: params,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("Message sent");
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("Message call failed");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Tried this and the breakpoint is hit, but the value for the `message` parameter is:  `"[object Object]"`

Comment: Where? is it in `success` handler for `ajax`? If yes, then just use `msg.d` . I mean , does ajax call goes well with HTTP status 200?

Comment: The breakpoint is hit in the codebehind- in `SendMessage(string message)`. But the value of `message` is `"[object Object]"`. I expected it to be something along the lines of a JSON string representation of the values I passed in the Ajax call...?

Comment: does - `document.getElementById("message").value` has actual string value?

Comment: Actually I had the `var params = "{'message':'" + message + "'}";` set to `var params = "{'message':'" + msg + "'}";` It works now but only sends the `message` and not the number.. It's a start anyway :)

Comment: Glad to know that worked. To use number, first you have to make another input parameter in `SendMessage` and in same manner pass number to webmethod.